# adding in array error (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a integer in a array but when ever I try to it, it throws an error saying

**undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass**

can you tell me what am I doing wrong

```
def bookmark_request
    data = params[:d]
    request_bookmarked = Request.getRequest(data)
    bookmarked_against_Request = Request.first
    request_bookmarked_2 = request_bookmarked
    bookmarked_against_Request_2 = bookmarked_against_Request
    bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << request_bookmarked[:_id]

  end
```

Comment: `bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites]` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash `bookmarked_against_Request_2` either doesnot have a `favourites` key or that key's value is `nil`.

To avoid such errors do:

```
# assuming if favourites is present it will always be an Array
bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites] << request_bookmarked[:_id] if bookmarked_against_Request_2[:favourites]
```